# Does using 2 OSs affect CPU speed?

Tags: windows, cpu

I have windows 7 already installed on my laptop and I would like to know if installing ubuntu as well would affect my processor's speed. Here are the specs for the processor: http://ark.intel.com/products/53442/Intel-Core-i3-2370M-Processor-(3M-Cache-2_40-GHz). The laptop came with 4GB of memory and a 500GB HD.

Answer (score 2):

No. You will only be able to run one OS at the time... Your CPU will be just fine. I'm currently dual booting my Centrino dual- core with no problems at all.

This all only counts if your not using VMWare or other Virtual machines... Running two OSs with the second OS running in a VM will certainly affect your CPU speed...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

I think ubuntu is a more responsive OS so it may seem things are faster, but the processor speed should be unchanged.

Bernie

Answer (score -1):

The only way for your CPU speed to change is if you are use software to overclock your processor in widows, but you appear to be using a laptop, so you can't overclock  anyway, there can be a minor impact on hard drive performance

Comment: How about Intel speedstep and similar power saving technologies? I'm afraid your statement isn't correct as it is.

Comment: It will not affect that, turbo is supported but it not easy to see when it is working via software; even if it not support something it would not affect windows in any way

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - it was a rhetorical question, since you wrote the only way for CPU speed to change was overclocking, which as a statement isn't correct.

Comment: well you could underclock, the clock speed will change between several speeds, to save power and reduce heat (windows does this but hides it)